# RCppParallel Programming Error Crashing R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rcpp

I have been trying to parallelize one of my Rcpp routines.  In doing so I have been trying to follow the [Parallel Distance Calculation](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/parallel-distance-matrix/) example from jjalaire.  Unfortunately, once I got everything coded up and started to play around, my R session would crash.  Sometimes after the first execution, sometimes after the third.  To be honest, it was a crap shoot as to when R would crash when I ran the routine.  So, I have paired down my code to a small reproducible example to play with.

**Rcpp File (mytest.cpp)**

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppParallel)]]
#include <RcppParallel.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace RcppParallel;

struct MyThing : public Worker {
  RVector<double> _pc;
  RVector<double> _pcsd;

  MyThing(Rcpp::NumericVector _pc, Rcpp::NumericVector _pcsd) : _pc(_pc), _pcsd(_pcsd){}

  void operator()(std::size_t begin, std::size_t end) {

    for(int j = begin; j <= end; j++) {      
      _pc[j] = 1;
//      _pcsd[j] = 1;
    }
  }    
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void calculateMyThingParallel() {

  NumericVector _pc(100);
  NumericVector _pcsd(100);

  MyThing mt(_pc, _pcsd);

  parallelFor(0, 100, mt);
}
```

**R Compilation and Execution Script (mytest.R)**

```
library(Rcpp)
library(inline)

sourceCpp('mytest.cpp')

testmything = function() {
  calculateMyThingParallel()
}

if(TRUE) {
  for(i in 1:20) {
    testmything()
  }
}
```

The error seems to be directly related to my setting of the _pc and _pcsd variables in the `operator()` method.  If I take those out things dramatically improve.  Based on the Parallel Distance Calculation example, I am not sure what it is that I have done wrong here.  I was under the impression that RVector was thread safe.  Although that is my impression, I know this is an issue with threads somehow.  Can anybody help me to understand why the above code randomly crashes my R sessions?

For information I am running the following:

- Windows 7
- R: 3.1.2
- Rtools: 3.1
- Rcpp: 0.11.3
- inline: 0.3.13
- RStudio: 0.99.62

Comment: If you ask on rcpp-devel JJ may see; if we leave it here he may not.

Comment: Roger...  I will cross post this in the interest of exposure.  If I get a good answer from over there I will bring it back here to close this out and make the QA avail to the SO community...

Comment: In light of the outcome I adjusted the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After cross-posting this question on the rcpp-devel list, a user responded and infomed me that my loop over `j` in the `operator()` method should go between `begin <= j < end` and not `begin <= j <= end` which is what I had.

I made that change and sure nuff, everything seems to be working right now.

seems like overextending ones reach past allocated memory spaces still results in unintended consequences...